# Is there a formal definition of the term meaning?

Tags: semantics, meaning

According to Wiktionary and Wikipedia,

- *[meaningfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics)* is "*the state or measure of being meaningful*",
- while *[meaningful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semasiology)* is "*having meaning, significant*",
- while *[meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Meaning)* is "*the information or concepts that a sender intends to convey, or does convey, in communication with a receiver*".

There is for example the seminal work "*[The meaning of meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Meaning)*" (Ogden, Richards, 1923) exploring the topic of *meaning*.

I do not know though, whether there are recent insights and more up-to-date definitions for example from recent *[hermeneutics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutics)* or [*semasiology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semasiology) studies i.e. sciences focusing on decoding word meanings.

What are then [formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system) i.e. non-colloquial definitions of the *meaninfulness* and *meaning* according to the recent research?

Comment: I leave it with this question as meaningfulness is full of meaning.

Comment: By "formal definition", do you mean like this: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/common_writing_assignments/definitions.html

Comment: Formal definitions exist only in formal contexts. In propositional calculus, for instance, the formal definition of 'meaning' is 'either True or False'. There are no other truth values in binary logic, and meaning is defined as truth value. So the propositions '2+2=4' and '2+3=5' have the same meaning because they're both True.

Comment: Have you looked at something like https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/word-meaning/ for an overview?

Comment: @jlawler of course there are other truth values, if \top, \bottom \beta and the like count for anything, which are however defined on the metalevel, not within the algebra. Otherwise, I agree there is no meaning without truth, and most meaning is basically symbolic, at least within the language

Comment: But truth values are only defined for statements. That means questions are meaningless, with that definition.

Comment: @matan-matika thank you very much for you link; while it is revised in late 2019, it can be a great candidate for an accepted answer unless there are even more recent insights which I doubt. So far I was thinking about that the "Meaning of the meaning" (Ogden, Richards,  1923) while being seminal can't be an up-to-date source.

Comment: What formal definition of formal definition are you relying on?

Comment: @user6726 thank you for this clarification inquiry: formal is meant here as opposite to colloquial.

Comment: So basically, "a scientific theory of", and not necessarily symbolic.

Answer (score 2):

[There are a lot of ideas of "meaning,"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning/) and some relate to linguistics and some do not.

Some theories might work with meaning as a thing that exists independently of humans. This view puts meaning outside of linguistics. There are lots of various formulations of this, from Plato's idea that there is an ideal world of meaning, to the notion that the world is composed of entities, truth values, and functions between them, based on the works of Gottlob Frege ([a view that allows for some cool linguistic semantics](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/yxiang/files/ho4_semantic-type-2014.pdf)). In this sort of theory, words **denote** entities.

Other theories work with an idea of meaning as something constructed by humans, and therefore, how people use language can give insight into what they think the world means. For example, Ludwig Wittgenstein posits that words only mean something because they are used within specific "language games" and nothing that exists independently of them. Another such theory is George Lakoff's "Embodied Mind" - which states that all meaning is derived from things people can directly sense, or metaphors extended out from those bodily understandings.

Many types of linguistics do not need to stick to a full understanding of *meaning*, just how words, phrases, sentences, etc. *relate to and express* meaning, and can work no matter which definition of "meaning" you take. (And some don't even think that all utterances express meaning, but sometimes exist for other reasons, like to change the world, like J. L. Austin wrote about in *How to Do Things with Words*)

Answer (score 1):

#### No, there is not a formal definition of "meaning"

If I were to make an attempt, meaning is what you make it.

Just kidding.

This is an interesting question and one I am facing as well. Meaning in my use is information gathered from something and knowledge iteratively applied to that information to sort of fit it into a box / clean it up. Once information has been "pampered" you have meaning. Put more succinctly, **meaning is knowledge applied to information**. There are formal definitions of knowledge and information out there in Cognitive Science.